# Bibliography STYLE [label] missing?

Tags: bibliographies, labels, apa-style

Please, I want my bibliography to look like this one:

```
[Wonko and Tsio 99b] Wonko, A. C., Tsio, F.: "Extended Use of Hyperlinks"; 
J.UCS, 5, 3 (1999), 225-327.
```

I tried "apalike" and "agsm" but the label in the beginning of the line as [Wonko and Tsio 99b] is always missing? Pleaaaaase Help me

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us if you employ any citation management packages, such as `natbib` or `apacite`. Please also edit your posting to provide the .bib source code for the formatted entry shown above.

Comment: In fact, I''m using jabref to manage my bibliography: 

\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{BibData}

Comment: So, indeed, you're using a citation management package: `natbib`.

Comment: Yes, what should I do to get bibliography as the following??? 
 [Wonko and Tsio 99b] Wonko, A. C., Tsio, F.: "Extended Use of Hyperlinks"; 
J.UCS, 5, 3 (1999), 225-32

Comment: I am honestly not aware of the existence of any ready-made bibliography style that produces a prefix such as `[Wonko and Tsio 99b]`. Especially not if the year is, later on in the same bib item, formatted as `1999` rather than as either `99b` or `1999b`. Is the "99" in "99b" in the prefix even an abbreviated reference to a year, or is it maybe something else? Sorry I can't provide any further help, except to suggest that you could hand-edit the formatted entries in the `.bbl` file to backfill the funky `[Wonko and Tsio 99b]` prefixes.

Comment: Thnx for your answer, I think that the data between the two brackets are the key of each entry in the bibliography